# New Azure Subscriptions are not listed with azure python sdk

Tags: python, azure, active-directory

I created 2 new subscriptions from Azure Portal, but I've not been able to list those newly created subscriptions using the python SDK. It lists the old subscriptions fine.

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
...
subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
for subscription in subscriptionClient.subscriptions.list():
    print subscription
...
```

I was having the same problem with CLI as well, but logging out and logging back in resolved the issue.

I don't see any other subscriptions operations to scan and refresh the subscriptions. Is there something I need to under Azure Active Directory to manage new subscriptions?

Comment: Are you talking about CLI 2.0? Because it's based in this exact SDK. I don't see any reason for your behavior :/

Comment: Yes, CLI 2.0. Me neither. Should I register another app in AAD and check if that reports all the subscriptions?

Comment: @SanjayKulkarni Based on my knowledge, subscriptions are stored in local cache. You could use `az account clear` (az logout) then `az login` again.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT, CLI worked fine after logging out and logging in. The problem is about fetching it using python apis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, which was caused by your client registed on Azure AD that have no permission to retrieve the information of these subscriptions. So the solution is to add permission for each subsription via add role like `Owner` for your client, as the figure below.

[image]

Then your code works fine, but I know the solution is not perfect for you. I'm looking for a better one.